# valueChangeListener and ajax execution order problem on selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm currently experiencing a strange phenomena, where setting the value to the model happens before executing valueChangeListener.

Basically what i would like to happen is :

1. I change the select menu
2. The new value get submitted using Ajax to update the myBean (using f:ajax)
3. Execute a query based on the newly submitted value (using valueChangeListener)
4. Render the table based on the result from the last query

But what happens when i run it is in this order, 1 - 3 - 2 - 4 (not 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 as i imagined)

Here's the part of the UI :

```
<h:selectOneMenu label="budget" id="budget"
    converter="genericConverter"
    value="#{myBean.budget}" 
    valueChangeListener="#{myBean.actionSearch}">

    <f:ajax render="myGrid" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose one .." noSelectionOption="true" />

    <f:selectItems ... />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And this is the excerpt from the bean :

```
public void actionSearch() {
    System.out.println("searching with this.budget == " + this.budget);
    ...
}
public void setBudget(String budget) {
    System.out.println("setting budget : " + budget);
    this.budget = budget;
}
```

And this is the output :

```
searching with this.budget == xxxx
setting budget : yyyy
```

What i would like is, setting the budget first from the new value selected in the UI, and then start searching based on the new UI. But i dont know how to achieve that.

And im using Tomcat 7 along with these :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I wonder what i did wrong ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `valueChangeListener` is executed during Validations phase, *before* the Update Model Values phase. It is intented to be able to get a handle of *both* the old and new value so that you can if necessary do some business stuff (logging?) based on the *real* change. In JSF 1.x this was however more than often (ab)used to invoke actions on a dropdown change only, but it has to be used in combination with `onchange="submit()"`, `immediate="true"`, [`FacesContext#renderResponse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29) and other stuffs. The selected value is to be obtained by [`ValueChangeEvent#getNewValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent.html#getNewValue%28%29) (the [`ValueChangeEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent.html) is supposed to be definied as method's argument).

For JSF 2.x you don't need the `valueChangeListener` anymore in such case. You're also not interested in the old value anyway. Use the `listener` attribute of [`<f:ajax>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) instead.

```
<f:ajax listener="#{bean.actionSearch}" />
```

This will be executed during Invoke Action phase, *after* Update Model Values phase.

Comment: Ah ! Now i understand more about this topic. I was surprised with this case because previously there's another case similar to this that works using valueChangeListener. And now i noticed that inside the method that works, i have the ValueChangeEvent method, and from the event object, i fetch the new value and update the model manually. I tried the listener solution on the ajax. Thank you as always !

Comment: And what if you ARE interested in the old value, for any reason? It seems to be the lost functionality :(